# Car vibrating when brake pressed in idle

Tags: ford, transmission, vibration, torque-converter

Have a 2018 ford ecosport (3 cyl) automatic. Comes with a torque converter gearbox.

Issue:

Mild constant vibrations when brake is pressed and transmission is in D. The vibration is lower in when in R and doesn't exist in P/N.

Car has run 27000 kms.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Has it always behaved this way, or is this a new behavior?

Comment: Thanks. I bought it used recently. So I'm not if this is normal behaviour or not. It is quite obvious and not very subtle. I didn't register it until i was stuck in a traffic stop for a extended period of time.

Comment: My first thought here is a problem with the brake booster or its vacuum line.

Comment: Could there be any fault with the transmission or engine mounts? Since it's happening only when in D or R to a lesser extent?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be a fault with the torque converter, maybe loose blades.

With park or neutral selected, there will be very little load on the torque converter since the transmission will have disconnected power to the drive train.  In Drive or Reverse, the torque converter will be transferring power to the drive train, all slip will be occurring in the torque converter, any faults will be more noticable.